ssh doesnt work when username has "/" in it
I am trying to ssh to my ubuntu22.04 server with username which has forward slash "/" in it. Ex: "tes/t"
i get the permission denied error.
It doesn't work if i have backslash "" also.
But in fedora username with "/" works and "" doesn't work.  What parameters decide this?
My requirement is that the username will have "/" due to some standards maintained for all users. i compared how is the behaviour diffrenet in my ubuntu and fedora machines:
when i ssh with user 'tes/t' to ubuntu machine,all characters after / is truncated and sent as "tes".
So ssh fails i guess. Even audit log registers the user as "tes".
ssh Log:
sshd[310956]: info Failed password for tes from 10.120.64.33 port 56498 ssh2
audit.log:
15:09:17.305Z [tes]: Login_Denied - - apparently_via=Remote ip=10.120.64.33 auth=PAM In
In fedora user is seen as tes/t only and succeeds.

A user name with a / in it is not POSIX compliant. This is probably allowed, because Ubuntu/Linux is not 100% POSIX compliant. However, by choosing to allow non-POSIX compliant names, you'll encounter errors like this. So to be safe, be POSIX compliant, especially for usernames.

You need to escape it. Fedora also abides by the 3.282 of the basedefs: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282

thanks for the reply. For my requirement user will have  "/" as per some standards observed. I have updated my origial question with more observation on issue and how username gets truncated when sent.

I can only begin to imagine problems for users that have the "/" character in their ID.  A big question that comes to mind is what the home directory will be.  Some times the powers that be will consider something crazy such as a seriously considered demand to allow UIDs to be alphanumeric.

thanks.  user containing a slash is not allowed on Ubuntu 22.04; systemd won't let you.
As per docmentation: https://systemd.io/USER_NAMES/
"Similar, no slashes, as these have special meaning in file system paths "
